# Cv-qualifications of prvalues in C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer

It appears that C++11 and C++14 treat cv-qualifications of prvalues differently.

C++11 sticks to the "classic" approach that has been around since C++98: according to 3.10/4 *"non-class prvalues always have cv-unqualified types"*.

C++14 contains a similar wording in 3.10/4, but it is presented as a note: *"[Note: class and array prvalues can have cv-qualified types; other prvalues always have cv-unqualified types. See Clause 5. —end note ]"*

And in Clause 5 it says:

> **6** If a prvalue initially has the type “cv T,” where T is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.<sup>1</sup>

This 5/6 entry is new in C++14. It now treats cv-qualifications of prvalues using the same approach that has always been used with results of reference type (see 5/5).

What could be the reason for this change? C++11 and before denied non-class prvalues the right to have any cv-qualifications. C++14 says that non-class, non-array prvalues *can* have cv-qualifications, but these cv-qualifications are discarded *prior to any further analysis*.

My guess would be that there are some new (for C++14) language features that can somehow "see" cv-qualifications of prvalues under the right circumstances (before the aforementioned adjustment takes place). Do they exist? And if so, what are these features?<sup>2</sup>

---

The question originated from following context: imagine a compiler that internally implements hidden parameter `this` of class `X` as a variable of type `X *const`. Since the compiler is required to expose `this` as a prvalue, that `const` should not lead to any problems in C++11 (or before), where scalar prvalues are never cv-qualified. But what about C++14? If the very same compiler exposes that `this` as a prvalue of type `X *const`, could it possibly lead to problems?

---

<sup>1</sup> There appears to be a contradiction between 5/6 and the note in 3.10/4 in C++14, but notes are not normative anyway. And I'm using a draft version of the text.

<sup>2</sup> My initial guess was `decltype`. And I even thought that I found the answer when I tried

```
std::cout << std::is_same<decltype((const int) 0), const int>::value << std::endl;
```

in GCC, which outputs `1`. However, seeing that Clang and VC++ output `0` (and that the spec of `decltype` does not seem to support this behavior) I'm inclined to believe that this is just a bug in GCC (starting from 6.1)

Comment: Actual code examples  regarding what you are talking about  are always nice.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: This is a question about conceptual behavior. The whole reason I'm asking the question is that I *cannot* find any code example that would exploit the above difference between C++11 and C++14. If the difference *cannot* be demonstrated by code, then I'd like to know what prompted the change in the standard text. If the difference *can* be demonstrated by code, then it would be nice to see that code.

Comment: I dislike the "language-lawyer" tag. It trivializes.

Comment: @Thomas This is definitely language lawyer territory.

Comment: @AnT so your question is why was the wording changed? Lots of the wording changed, to perhaps be more accurate or nuanced?.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Great. So, in what regard is the new wording "more accurate or nuanced"? That's basically what my question is about.

Comment: This was core issue 1261, which has zero discussion in the public issue list, but I think it's just wording cleanup. E.g., given `const int f();`, `f()` is a prvalue and its type is, according to [expr.call], "the return type of the statically chosen function", which would be `const int`, and some sort of wording is needed to make that `const` go away.

Comment: As to `this`, the standard exhaustively specifies the type of `this`. Anything else is nonconforming, period. And no, nothing can see the pre-adjustment type; that's what "prior to any further analysis" means. This is why people often say "an expression never has reference type".

Comment: @T.C.: I'm talking about internal implementation details/tricks. GCC up to version 4.8.5 was known to react to `int *p = this` code with "error: cannot convert 'S* const' to 'int*' in initialization" message (note the `const`). VC++ does the same thing to this day. Apparently, this is/was a rather popular implementational trick. And as long as no language feature can detect this "non-conformance", these compilers are free to use that trick. GCC diagnostic message no longer mentions `const` in this case. Maybe they abandoned the practice, or maybe they just tweaked the diagnostic message...

Comment: Well yes, GCC used to have problems with code like `S*&& p = this;`. Now they don't.

Comment: @T.C.: Thank you! Great example! VC++ also fails on this initialization.

Comment: So apparently [GCC's internal representation of `this` was a const lvalue](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-03/msg01231.html).

Comment: @T.C. Unless GCC used to allow `&this` as an extension, which would be surprising, it couldn't be a true lvalue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [commit on github](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/c9505d3aee7a0d0ff148330ad05224f519635cdc), this was done to resolve [CWG1261: Explicit handling of cv-qualification with non-class prvalues](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1261)

Based on comments to the question it seems there was room for surprising variations in type category of `this` (formally a **prvalue**) and that [gcc formerly](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-03/msg01231.html) and MSVC currently instead used a **const lvalue**.

The wording tightens up the hole to be explicit that, e.g., even if `this` is by some compiler-internal magic a prvalue of type `X* const`, *prior to any further analysis* it is adjusted to `X*`.

Similarly, your given example does look like a gcc bug. Possibly `decltype` isn't looking at the value type before applying the c-style cast.

The reason it's now a note in [basic.lval]/4 is that it's now a consequence of the new text in [expr]/6, rather than specifying the rule in [basic.lval]/4.

Full credit to [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) for having basically answered this in the comments on the question, including the reference to the gcc bug-fix, and various other examples of previously under-specified behaviours for *cv-qualified non-class non-array prvalues*.

Comment: Jason Merrill wrote "_When 'this' appears in an expression, it should be an rvalue rather than a const lvalue; in C++11, the distinction matters._" C++11? An rvalue was never like a const lvalue in any point of C++ history.

Comment: @curiousguy; Prior to C++11 you couldn’t use `decltype` and rvalue references to distinguish them (but maybe `const_cast` could have done it?).

Comment: @DavisHerring You mean `C * const &that = this; const_cast<C*&>(that) = new C;`?

Comment: @curiousguy: Just `const_cast<C*&>(this)`—assigning to it might be undefined behavior, but if it’s an rvalue then the cast shouldn’t compile (if I remember my C++03 correctly).

Comment: @DavisHerring Or simply `&this`

Comment: @curiousguy: It could theoretically be a temporary, I guess, but it makes sense.