# Which of these conversions should be ambiguous?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, conversion-operator, copy-initialization

I have some code like the following:

```
class bar;

class foo
{
public:
    operator bar() const;
};

class bar
{
public:
    bar(const foo& foo);
};

void baz() {
    foo f;
    bar b = f;   // [1]

    const foo f2;
    bar b2 = f2; // [2]
}
```

GCC gives an error at [2] but not [1].  Clang gives an error on both, and apparently MSVC gives an error on neither.  Who's right?

Comment: Because in the first case only the bar() constructor will match, in the second both the the bar operator in foo and bar constructor will match the const foo argument.

Comment: add `operator bar();` (notice there is no const) and both of them should be ambiguous

Comment: @tobi303 `bar b = f;` still works fine if only the conversion operator is declared, so it's not exactly true that `foo::operator bar() const` only works on a `const foo`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes well.. when I think about it I realize that my comment was non-sense. Of course a `const` method can be called on a non-const instance... I wonder who upvoted it :P

Comment: I believe it actually should be ambiguous in both cases now. But the relevant part of the standard is extremely complicated so I am not entirely certain.   I did observe that clang, and gcc with `-pedantic` flag, both reject `bar b = f;`, but gcc accepts it without `-pedantic` ; so maybe there is a GNU extension in play

Comment: clang complains on first conversion https://wandbox.org/permlink/fljvSm8gK2PYhCnm gcc on second https://wandbox.org/permlink/bWq4X1h4lQcZD2Qn.

Comment: What is more funny visual studio compiler  doesn't report an error http://rextester.com/FDX74810 :)

Comment: @MarekR add `-pedantic` flag to second one, technically gcc requires that for ISO compliant behaviour

Comment: overload resolution involving the cast operators has always been an impenetrable murk to me :)

Comment: @MarekR: Historical non-conformance in MSVC. Visual Studio 2017's `/permissive-` flag causes them both to be ambiguous, probably due to fixing [Do not treat copy initialization as direct initialization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/). [rextester](http://rextester.com) uses Visual Studio 2015, but you can see this failing in Visual Studio 2017 on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/.

Comment: @TBBie Thanks for the answer!  I guess the only remaining question is, what exactly are the semantics of the GCC extension that's in play here?

Comment: Three-way compiler test, all doing the right thing when asked: https://godbolt.org/g/AcUCir

Comment: Without -pedantic, g++ selects `bar(const foo&)` over `foo::operator bar() const` for `foo` -> `bar`.

It *might* be g++'s definition of `this`, I have a vague recollection that g++ had a non-standard definition of `this` (as an `xvalue &`), not a `const lvalue &`, or something like that. That would worsen `foo::operator bar() const` perhaps, since the initial conversion sequence would not be "Identity".

Comment: I tracked down that 'vague recollection': https://stackoverflow.com/a/43013917/166389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Ambiguous. (Also, if you're stopping at the tl;dr, then the `language-lawyer` tag might not be your cup-of-tea. ^_^)

### Spoiler

Both candidates have a single `const foo&` parameter, which binds equally to a `const foo` or `foo` argument. No other rules appear that would prefer one or the other function.

---

Breaking it down against the [current C++ working draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/)

## Initializers [[dcl.init]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init)

In both cases

- we are performing copy-initialization ([[dcl.init]/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#15))
- the destination type is a class type ([[dcl.init]/17.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6))

  - (X) initializer expression is not a prvalue ([[dcl.init]/17.6.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.1))
  - (X) source type is not the same or derived from the destination type ([[dcl.init]/17.6.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2))
  - User-defined conversion sequences are enumerated from [[over.match.copy]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.copy) and the best chosen by [overload resolution](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match).

## Copy-initialization of class by user-defined conversion [[over.match.copy]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.copy)

`T` is the type being intialised, in both cases this is `bar`.
`S` is the type of the initializer expression, in the two cases `foo` and `const foo` respectively.

- converting constructors of `T` are candidates ([[over.match.copy]/1.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.copy#1.1))

  - `bar::bar(const foo& foo);` is a candidate
- the type of the initializer expression is `_cv_ S` so non-explicit [conversion functions](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.fct) are considered: ([[over.match.copy]/1.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.copy#1.2))

  - `foo::operator bar() const` is not hidden within `foo` or within `const foo`, and yields `bar` which is the same as `T`, and hence is a candidate.

So our candidate list is the same in both cases:

- `bar::bar(const foo& foo)`
- `foo::operator bar() const`

In both cases, we have a [user-defined conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.user) consisting of:

1. Standard conversion of source type to user-defined conversion argument
2. User-defined conversion (one of the above two functions) to result type
3. Standard conversion of result type to target type

If we select the constructor, the "result type" is "a prvalue of the cv-unqualified version of the destination type whose result object is initialized by the constructor" ([[dcl.init]/17.6.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.3)), so for both candidate functions, the second Standard Conversion is **Identity** (`bar` -> `bar`).

## Overload resolution [[over.match]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match)

### Subsetting the viable candidate functions [[over.match.viable]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.viable)

Per [[dcl.init]/17.6.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.3), the initializer expression is going to be the argument to the selected call, in the two cases `foo` and `const foo` respectively.

#### `bar::bar(const foo& foo)`

- One argument in the list of arguments, exactly one parameter. ([[over.match.viable]/2.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.viable#2.1))
- No associated constraints ([[over.match.viable]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.viable#3))
- Implicit conversion sequence exists from both `foo` and `const foo` to `const foo&` ([[over.match.viable]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.viable#4))
- Initial standard conversion is **Identity conversion** in both cases: [[over.best.ics]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#5) => [[over.ics.ref]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref#1) for direct reference binding:

  - `const foo` is reference-compatible with both `foo` and `const foo` as `const` is more cv-qualified than both `const` and nothing. [[dcl.init.ref]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4)
  - `const foo&` binds directly to an lvalue `foo` and an lvalue `const foo`. [[dcl.init.ref]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5)
- **Viable**

#### `foo::operator bar() const`

- One argument in the list of arguments, exactly one [implicit object](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.copy#2) parameter. ([[over.match.viable]/2.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.viable#2.1))

  - Implicit object parameter is `const foo&` in both cases ([[over.match.funcs]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#4))
- No associated constraints ([[over.match.viable]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.viable#3))
- Implicit conversion sequence exists from both `foo` and `const foo` to `const foo&` ([[over.match.viable]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.viable#4))
- Initial standard conversion is **Identity conversion** in both cases, see above.
- **Viable**

### Select the best viable function [[over.best.ics]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics)

Both are **Identity => User Defined Conversion => Identity**, i.e., are [user-defined conversion sequences](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.user).

#### Ranking conversion sequences [over.ics.rank](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank)

Can we establish a ranking between the sequences? Only if [one of the following applies](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3)

- (X) Not list-initialization sequences ([[over.ics.rank]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.1))
- (X) Not a standard conversion sequence ([[over.ics.rank]/3.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2))
- (X) The two sequences do not contain "the same user-defined conversion function or constructor or [...] initialize the same class in an aggregate initialization" ([[over.ics.rank]/3.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.3))

Conversion sequences are **indistinguishable**, i.e., neither is better nor worse

#### Best viable function [over.match.best](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best)

Is either function a 'better' function? Only if [one of the following applies](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1)

- (X) Neither is a better conversion sequence ([[over.match.best]/1.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.3))
- (X) Second standard conversion is the same ([[over.match.best]/1.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.4))
- (X) Not direct reference binding a reference to a function type ([[over.match.best]/1.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.5))
- (X) Neither is a function template specialisation ([[over.match.best]/1.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.6) and [[over.match.best]/1.7](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.7))
- (X) Neither is constrained ([[over.match.best]/1.8](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.8))
- (X) One is a constructor for `bar`, but the other is not a constructor for a base class of `bar` ([[over.match.best]/1.9](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.9))
- (X) No deduced class types ([[over.match.best]/1.10](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.10 and [[over.match.best]/1.11](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.11)
- (X) Neither is a constructor template ([[over.match.best]/1.12](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.12))

Neither is a 'better' function, so the **call is ill-formed**. [[over.match.best]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#2)