# Binding const rvalues reference to non-const rvalues?

Tags: c++, reference-binding

The following quotes are needed in the question:

[[dcl.init.ref]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.ref#5):

> 5- A reference to type “`cv1 T1`” is initialized by an expression of
> type “`cv2 T2`” as follows:
>
> - (5.1) [..]
> - (5.2) [..]
> - (5.3) **Otherwise, if the initializer expression**
>
>   - (5.3.1) **is an rvalue** (but not a bit-field) or function lvalue **and “`cv1 T1`” is reference-compatible with “`cv2 T2`”**, or
>   - (5.3.2) [..]
>
> **then the value of the initializer expression in the first case** and the result of the conversion in the second case **is called the converted initializer. If the converted initializer is a prvalue, its type T4 is adjusted to type “cv1 T4” ([conv.qual]) and the temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied. In any case, the reference is bound to the resulting glvalue** (or to an appropriate base class subobject).

(**emphasis mine**)

[[expr.type]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#2):

> If a prvalue initially has the type “`cv T`”, where `T` is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

---

Consider the following example:

```
const int&& r1 = 0;
```

Taking `cv1 T1` as `const int`, and `cv2 T2` as `int`

It's clear that bullet [[dcl.init.ref]/(5.3.1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.ref#5.3.1) is applied here. The initializer expression is an rvalue (prvalue); and `cv1 T1` (`const int`) is reference-compatible with `cv2 T2` (`int`). And since that the converted initializer is prvalue, its type `T4` (`int`) is adjusted to `cv1 T4` (`const int`). Then, temporary materialization is applied.

But, per [expr.type]/2, before applying temporary materialization conversion, `cv1 T4` (`const int`) becomes `int` again. Then, by applying temporary materialization, we've got an xvalue denoting an object of type `int`. Then the reference is bound to the resulting glvalue.

Here's my first question. The reference `r1` is reference to `const int` and the resulting glvalue is an xvalue denoting an object of type `int`. So how `r1`, which is of type `const int&&`, is now binding to an xvalue of type `int`? Is this valid binding? Is any missing wording? Am I misunderstood/missed something?

---

Consider another last example:

```
const int&& r2 = static_cast<int&&>(0);
```

The same wording as above applies: The initializer expression is an rvalue (xvalue) and `cv1 T1` (`const int`) is reference-compatible with `cv2 T2` (`int`). And since that the converted initializer is an xvalue not prvalue, `[conv.qual]` or even `[conv.rval]` is not applied (i.e, the condition *"If the converted initializer is a prvalue, .."*) isn't satisfied.

I know that `[conv.rval]` isn't needed here since the initializer expression is already an xvalue, but `[conv.qual]` is required.

And that's my last question. The reference `r2` is reference to `const int` and the resulting glvalue is an xvalue denoting an object of type `int`. So how `r2`, which is of type `const int&&`, is now binding to an xvalue of type `int`? Is this valid binding? Is any missing wording? Am I misunderstood/missed something?

Comment: You can have a const reference to a non-const object.  What you can't have is the opposite, i.e a non-const reference to a const object.

Comment: You asked *So how r1, which is of type const int&&, is now binding to an xvalue of type int?*  Doesn't that answer what you asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here's my first question. The reference `r1` is reference to `const int` and the resulting glvalue is an xvalue denoting an object of type `int`. So how `r1`, which is of type `const int&&`, is now binding to an xvalue of type `int`? Is this valid binding?

Yes, that's what happens. I fail to see the issue here.

> I know that `[conv.rval]` isn't needed here since the initializer expression is already an xvalue, but `[conv.qual]` is required.

No it isn't. Again, I fail to see the issue.

There is, in fact, no rule that says that a reference of type `T&&`, can only refer to an object whose type is exactly `T`. A `const int&&` can refer to an `int` object. The concept of *reference-compatibility* was invented in order to describe what types of objects a reference can refer to.

Comment: "_The concept of reference-compatibility was invented in order to describe what types of objects a reference can refer to._" So do you mean that if `cv1 T1` is reference-compatible with `cv2 T2`, then a reference to `cv1 T1` can bind to an object of type `cv2 T2`?

Comment: In the first example, does this wording is correct `And since that the converted initializer is prvalue, its type T4 (int) is adjusted to cv1 T4 (const int). Then, temporary materialization is applied.

But, per [expr.type]/2, before applying temporary materialization conversion, cv1 T4 (const int) becomes int again. Then, by applying temporary materialization, we've got an xvalue denoting an object of type int` I mean does this what's actually happening?

Comment: @H.K. yes to both.

Comment: Thanks. But are you see there's a redundancy here? I mean `T4` is adjusted to `cv1 T4` using [conv.qual]; then before applying [conv.rval] `cv1 T4` becomes again `T4`; So, I see that [conv.qual] is unnecessary here because note, `T4` is adjusted using [conv.qual] to `cv1 T4` then the adjustments are ignored per [expr.type]/2. So why do we need to do so?

Comment: @H.K. Comments should be used to seek clarification about answers, not to raise additional lines of inquiry that weren't present in the original question.