# Cv-qualification of prvalues during reference binding

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, prvalue

Consider this example:

```
const int& r2 = 5;
```

The rules governing reference-initialization are found in [[dcl.init.ref]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5):

> A reference to type “`cv1 T1`” is initialized by an expression of
> type “`cv2 T2`” as follows:
>
> - (5.1) [..]
> - (5.2) [..]
> - (5.3) Otherwise, if the initializer expression
>
>   - (5.3.1) is an rvalue [..] and “`cv1 T1`” is reference-compatible with “`cv2 T2`”, or
>   - (5.3.2) [..]
>
> then the initializer expression [..] is called the converted initializer. **If the converted initializer is a prvalue, its type `T4` is adjusted to type “`cv1 T4`” ([conv.qual]) and the temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied**. In any case, the reference is bound to the resulting glvalue [..].

Here, The converted initializer is a prvalue of type `T4` (`int`); then it's adjusted to `cv1 T4` (`const int`). But [[expr.type]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#2) states:

> If a prvalue **initially** has the type “`cv T`”, where `T` is a
> cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression
> is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

One said to me that this rule (`[expr.type]/2`) does not apply to specifically this case. And I need to know the reason behind that.

I claim that the reason for not applying `[expr.type]/2` is because **initially** (before adjustment) the type of the prvalue is `T4` (`int`) i.e, it's cv-unqualified type, so `[expr.type]/2` cannot be applied since the initial type of the prvalue is not cv-qualified type. Even after the adjustment to `cv1 T4`, the rule [expr.type]/2 also doesn't apply because `cv1 T4` is not the **initial** type of the prvalue. **My question is**: Are those *correct reasons*?

Indeed both questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54381791/cv-qualifications-of-prvalues-revisited) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989034/cv-qualifications-of-prvalues-in-c14) are relatively similar but *specifically* I'm asking a specific, different question regarding the rule [expr.type]/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the mentioned case (`const int& r2 = 5;`) should fall into [dcl.init.ref]/(5.4.2). I think this is related to a mischange introduced by [P0135R1](https://wg21.link/p0135r1) and fixed by [CWG2481](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2481.html).

> One said to me that this rule (`[expr.type]/2`) does not apply to specifically this case. And I need to know the reason behind that.

I think that is a non-standard comprehension of the cases addressed by CWG2481, which should be equivalent to the standard one. That is just saying "cv-qualification is not stripped".

---

Perhaps the use of "rvalue" in [dcl.init.ref]/(5.3.1) is <s>wrong</s> unintended and the value category should be "xvalue". <s>I'll [contact CWG chair for clarification](https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues).</s>

I've opened an [editorial issue #5821](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/5821) to ask whether "its type `T4` is adjusted to type “*cv1* `T4`”" (5.3) and "considering the type of the prvalue to be “*cv1* `T1`”" (5.4.2) have the same meaning.

---

Edit: [CWG2657](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2657.html) has been opened for this.